# WireShark - Can I decode UTF-8 data in packets?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, decode, encode, wireshark

In Wireshark, how can I see non-ASCI characters in packets? some of my network data is in UTF-8 encoding and I would like Wireshark to recognize it.

- Is there a plugin for it?
- I found [this](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/625/displaying-utf-8-in-wireshark-packet-info-tree) but maybe there is something new about that.
- I want to see Arabic, Chinese and Hebrew.

Comment: Which Unicode representation?  UTF-8?  UTF-16 (big-endian or little-endian)?

Comment: I've updated your question accordingly.

Comment: I have export the packet and the file is encoded as utf-8 and the result is perfected!

Comment: @Sisyphus what version are you using? what about writing a well done answer? Accompanied with screen shots.

Comment: @0x90 I am using wireshark 1.12.1 on Mac OS. Right click on the item you want to export , select "export selected packet bytes ... ", and follow the default setting and choose one position to store the file. And open the file, it was encoded with utf-8. And the Chinese character was well printed instead of garbled code. I haven't tried for other encodings.

Answer (score 7):

> In Wireshark, how can I see non-ASCI characters in a packet? some of my data in the packets is in the UTF-8 encoding and I would like Wireshark to recognize it.
>
> - Is there a plugin for it?

No - that's not what Wireshark plugins do.  They can dissect packets, and do statistical analysis, but they can't affect the routines that a dissector uses.

> - I found [this](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/625/displaying-utf-8-in-wireshark-packet-info-tree) but maybe there is something new about that.

What's new is that you can (and should) specify the character encoding when dissecting a string.

What's *not* new is that Wireshark currently doesn't try to fully handle strings it's told are UTF-8 encoded.  It can't just blindly try to display them, as they might not be valid UTF-8 strings, or they might contain non-graphic characters.  We haven't yet added full UTF-8 support (or support for other character encodings that handle non-ASCII characters).